# how to define labels at machine learning excepts one-hot-encoding

Tags: machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I want to make model that can classify attributes not class.

for example, when I input this image
[image]

my model output ' this furniture have [ brown color, 4 legs, fabric sheet ] '

I used pre-trained ResNet but it doesn't work well.
so I tried to make new model but I can't define Label values

I think it can't achieve my goal with one-hot-encoding.

how can I implements?
give me some Idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to say that this *probably* doesn't work with one-hot-encoding, let's take a look at what options you do have.

### Option 1: Still one hot encoding

If you want your model to only have a limited number of attributes outputted, and they are non-overlapping, you can have k one-hot encoded output layers.

For example, if you have the attributes `color`, `# of legs`, `material`, these are never overlapping. You can then have your model predict a color, number of legs, and a material for each input image. These can be represented and learned using 3 one-hot encoded vectors.

#### Pros:

- typically nicer to train
- will not have colliding predictions

#### Cons:

- require separation of class

### Option 2: Don't use softmax, sigmoid FTW

If you use a sigmoidal activation instead of softmax (which is what I am assuming you're using), each output node is independent of other output nodes. This way, each output will give its own probability likelihood.

In this scenario, your label will not be one-hot encoded, but rather it will be a binary vector, with variable number of `1`s and `0`s.

Instead of finding the max probability, you would most likely want to take a threshold probability, i.e. take all outputs with a probability of >80% as the predicted labels when evaluating.

#### Pros:

- Does not require hand-made separation of attributes (since we are treating each class as independent of one another)
- Easy representation for variable number of attributes

#### Cons:

- Mathematically, and from experience as well, this tends to be much harder to train
- It is possible (and quite frankly, it will be likely) you will get colliding predictions, i.e. both `4 legs` and `3 legs` may come out of your neural network. You will need to handle these cases.

This really comes down to a preference thing, and based on what sort of data you are working with. If you can choose attributes in a way that you can cleanly separate options for the neural network to choose from like `color` and `material` (assuming you can't have two colors or two materials), the first option is probably best.

There are a couple of other ways to approach this problem, but these seem most closely applicable.